# Getting docker log output into files on mac and linux

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, filebeat

I have a set of containers orchestrated via docker compose.  Some of the containers write to a log file inside the container and I use volumes to make those available on the host.  However some containers are only logging via stdout/stderr.  Te issue I'm having is I cant figure out how to get that information into a regular file on the host.  It sounds like Docker on Linux doesn't write the logs to files in a way that are accessible to the host.

My ultimate goals are:

- Have each containers logs, as a file, available on the host (for
  filebeat).

  Have the same setup runnable on Mac and Linux.

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve containers logs directed to stdout/stderr by using the docker logs command.

Be careful, docker logs just read a .json file that is located into your docker installation, for example :

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/<your container hash>/*.json
```

This file will be deleted if you recreate your container and the path won't be the same, hash is different for every new containers.

If you want to save it into a regular file, parsed json, you can simply do :

```
docker logs my-container > log.txt
```

Comment: /var/lib/docker/containers/ this directory doesn't exist on macs.  That is part of my problem.  Doing docker logs isn't an option as I need the files in realtime.

Comment: You would think this would work, but I am getting and empty file when I do that.